# wget average data rate is not consistent with download file size divided by time

Tags: wget

For a few experiments I ran wget to download a file to measure data rates. The file (size) is always the same, about 292 MiB. 
The average download speed shown by wget does not match the file size divided by the shown time. How does that happen? I couldn't find anything how wget exactly calculates the average data rate.

If that matters: I was experimenting with MPTCP and measuring data rates over different links. AFAIK wget shouldn't care whether plain TCP or MPTCP is used.

An excerpt of the results

```
 9.6 MB/s    0:28 min (data rate is lower but takes less time?)
10.0 MB/s    0:29 min (?)
10.1 MB/s    0:29 min (?)
10.3 MB/s    0:33 min (?)
10.5 MB/s    0:30 min
```

The rate I refer to is the rate that is displayed after the download is finished, like in the last line here:

```
debian-9.9.0-amd64-netinst.i 100%[==============================================>] 292,00M  9,69MB/s    in 29s

2019-07-17 12:24:25 (10,1 MB/s) - "debian-9.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso.1" saved [306184192/306184192]
```

Comment: Were there stoppages in the download? Times when wget had to retry connecting?

Comment: wget didn't show anything about stoppages. After these tests I pinged over the different links - no packet losses.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the average speed of the last time slice displayed, not the average speed of the entire download.